# DatePickerDialog inside ShowDIalog() deprecated

Tags: android-dialog, android-datepicker

I have next code:

```
dateDisplay1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onClick(View v) {
        option = 1;
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
    }
});
```

And the onCreateDialog function:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, dayDate, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),      cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timeDate, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);
    }
    return null;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to adapt the showDialog(), that is deprecated, to a DialogFragment, with no success. The code below works but it is not best practices. So I would like to correct the code.

How woould you implement that?

Answer (score 10):

```
public class ReminderEditActivity extends Activity {
    private Button mDateButton;
    private Button mTimeButton;
    public Calendar mCalendar;
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    private static final String TIME_FORMAT = "kk:mm";
    DialogFragment dateFragment;
    DialogFragment timeFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reminder_edit);
        mTimeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reminder_time);
        mDateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reminder_date);
        mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDatePickerDialog(v);
            }
            });
        mTimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showTimePickerDialog(v);
            }
            });

    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        dateFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        dateFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

    }

    public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
        timeFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        timeFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }

    public void updateDateButtonText() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        String dateForButton = dateFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime());
        mDateButton.setText(dateForButton);
    }
    private void updateTimeButtonText() {
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT);
        String timeForButton = timeFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime());
        mTimeButton.setText(timeForButton);
        }

    class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
            updateDateButtonText();
        }
    }

    public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                    DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            updateTimeButtonText();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is helpful for displaying calender in alert dialog with restricted past days in my adapter.

```
  changedate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(type.equals("1") ) {

                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
                        mmonth = selectedMonth;
                        mday = selectedDay;
                        myear = selectedYear;


                        changedate.setText(new StringBuilder()
                                .append(mday).append("-").append(mmonth + 1).append("-")
                                .append(myear).append(" "));

                    }

                };
                switch (DATE_DIALOG_ID) {
                    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:

                        dat1 = new DatePickerDialog(context, datePickerListener, myear, mmonth, mday);
                        c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
                        Date newDate = c.getTime();
                        dat1.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate.getTime()-1000);
                        dat1.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate.getTime() - (newDate.getTime() % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
                        dat1.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, context.getString(R.string.ok), dat1);
                        dat1.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, context.getString(R.string.cancel), dat1);


                }
                dat1.show();
            }

        }
    });
```